# How to define convenient unit of measurement syntax in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, units-of-measurement

In [this example](http://groovy.dzone.com/news/domain-specific-language-unit-) of using Groovy, the author describes how one can use Groovy tricks to define a syntax for units of measurements, such that you can write, e.g.,

```
3.cm + 12.m * 3 - 1.km
```

and have it work as expected.  Is there any way to define a similarly clever syntax for associating units of measurement with numbers in CoffeeScript?  (I'm very new to CoffeeScript; sorry if this is something that has already been solved or has an obvious answer.)

Answer (score 2):

I think [BasicWolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12507065/581845) is the most idiomatic, as you could have those functions in their own module and only import them only when you want to use them without having to pollute the global namespace or the JS builtin objects.

In Groovy, you can use a [Category](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Category+and+Mixin+transformations) to avoid polluting the builtin classes with extra methods.

But, if you don't care about adding things to the builtin objects, you can go a step further and use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) to make the syntax of this exactly like Groovy's example :)

```
Object.defineProperties Number.prototype,
  km: {get: -> @ * 1000}
  m:  {get: -> @}
  cm: {get: -> @ * 0.01}

console.log 3.cm + 12.m * 3 - 1.km # -> -963.97
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it, but this works:

```
Number::cm = ->
  this / 100

Number::m = ->
  this

Number::km = ->
  this * 1000


3.cm() + 12.m() * 3 - 1.km() # evaluates to -963.97
```

You can't get rid of the parentheses because `3.cm` references the function `cm` instead of invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do it that way with CoffeeScript. What you can do is something like (in both CoffeeScript and JavaScript):

```
cm(3) + m(12) * 3 - km(1)
```

Here `cm()`, `m()`, `km()` are functions which convert the values to e.g. meters. In terms of CoffeeScript the following expression

```
(cm 3) + 3 * (m 12) - (km 1)
```

is also valid.

Comment: The last snippet is not right. It compiles to: `cm(3 + 3 * m(12 - km(1)))`. You could use `(cm 3) + (m 3) * 3 - (km 1)`, which IMO is more consistent with the avoiding parentheses motto :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I personally always use parentheses :)

Comment: Yeah. Parenthesization in CoffeeScript is kind of a hot topic :P